# Error Code: 38 DB::Exception: Cannot parse date: value is too short: Cannot parse Date from String:while executing Insert into clickhouse db

Tags: sql, rdbms, clickhouse

I am creating a table in ClickHouse DB using this command

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE (id Int,sample_date Date ) Engine = MergeTree Primary Key id
```

Then I am storing the data into the table created above using this command

```
INSERT INTO SAMPLE (id,sample_date) VALUES (123,'')
```

This Is giving me error as

```
Error Code: 38 DB::Exception: Cannot parse date: value is too short: Cannot parse Date from String:
```

Comment: I don't want to store null values as it take more time/storage to store prefer to store empty string

Comment: Full Error :- DB::Exception: Cannot parse date: value is too short: Cannot parse Date from String: while executing 'FUNCTION if(isNull(_dummy_0) : 3, defaultValueOfTypeName('Date') :: 2, _CAST(_dummy_0, 'Date') :: 4) -> if(isNull(_dummy_0), defaultValueOfTypeName('Date'), _CAST(_dummy_0, 'Date')) Date : 1': While executing ValuesBlockInputFormat. Stack trace:

Comment: You can't store an empty string in a Date column, since it's internally stored as a 16 bit integer.  You could store a 0, which is `1970-01-01`

Comment: How to store null value then ?

Comment: Use `NULL` to store a null value. E.g. `INSERT INTO SAMPLE (id,sample_date) VALUES (123, NULL)`. Or skip that column, `INSERT INTO SAMPLE (id) VALUES (123)`.

Comment: An empty string, 0 and 1970-01-01, are all not null.

Comment: should I specify null in front of the column while creating the table

Comment: id | sample_date 123 | java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.time.LocalDate.getYear()" because "d" is null

Comment: this is the output I received in dbveaver when I am storing date as NULL in the table and